# ways to improve Testing skills as a Mobile application tester

Tags: testing

Changing Career from iPhone application developer to Tester makes me to learn about basic testing.I need to hone my testing skill.what are the ways to improve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm testing ~5-10 (small) applications per year so I'm no expert by any means, but this are several things I find quite useful:

- **Think out of the box.** You are familiar with the workflow of the application. You know what your designers thought when implementing
  functions. After checking these regular patterns I try to think about
  the app completely different and try out new unconventional
  workflows.
- **Try breaking it.** Type text where numbers should be, try copying text from the outside into numberfields, tap multiple buttons and
  hold them while using one normally. Use your UIElements while turning
  the device. Be creative about it - Go apeshit on it! ;-)

> "A common mistake people make when trying to design something
>   completely foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete
>   fools." - Douglas Adams

- If allowed, **hand this application to a 10 year old** and see how he
  uses it.
- **Go fast.** When jumping between views your eyes will notice small shifted pixels automatically.
- When done, check out this awesome tool: [UIAutoMonkey](https://github.com/jonathanpenn/ui-auto-monkey) (Coming back to that apeshit part ;))

Answer (score 1):

If you are entering in the field of testing, then make sure you follow the below steps/things :

- Clear the basic concepts of testing (You can refer the loads of online material for this)
- Go for Manual testing first as it will be easy for the first time.
- Try to break the things.
- Test only when you have clear guidelines. Don't assume anything.

Happy Testing !!